# Getting an error “Cannot convert undefined or null to object” on Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Getting an error “Cannot convert undefined or null to object” on this VueJs Slider. It is working here http://novo.evbox.com/ (Its the first component on the page) . The functionality works but I would like to solve the error in the console. Does anyone have any insights? 
Note: I have removed some code for brevity.

```
<template>
      <div id="vue-slider">
        <div
          id="button-toggle-container"
          class="button-toggle-container flex justify-center justify-between mt3 mb4 mx-auto"
        >
          <button
            class="button-toggle"
            v-for="(slidePanelKey, mainIndex) in Object.keys(slider)"
            :id="slidePanelKey"
            :key="mainIndex"
            @click="setActivePanel(mainIndex)"
            :class="{active: mainIndex == activeButtonIndex}"
          >{{ slidePanelKey }}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "slider",
  props: {
    slide: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      slider: null,
      retrieved: {
        slider: false
      }
    }
  },
    mounted: function () {
            // Retrieve slides data.
            axios
                .get(
                    "/api/?hash=API-KEY&type=slider" +
                    "&context=" + this.getContext()
                )
                .then(response => {this.slider = response.data.data
                  this.slide = Object.values(this.slider)
                })
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                .catch(error => console.log(error))


        },

  },

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.then(response => {
  if(response.data && typeof response.data.data === 'object') {
    this.slide = Object.values(response.data.data)
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey there, try to add some explanation with your answer to help people use it.

Comment: The better answer because the `typeof` solves the problem of the data being "truthy" but not an object, in one go. In TypeScript it can be simplified to `if (typeof response?.data?.data === 'object')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve the issue

```
.then(response => {
  if(response.data && response.data.data) {
    this.slider = response.data.data
    this.slide = Object.values(this.slider)
  }
})
```